# Voltdb + gwan with c++

Tags: c++, g-wan, voltdb

I have decided use GWAN like my application server and I wish use voltdb for storage the data. Anybody has employed both together?.

I will develop it in C++.

Comment: G-WAN is not generally considered to be production-ready. I would strongly advise you to consider alternatives.

Comment: G-WAN hosts Web sites (including self) since 2009. Thanks for not spreading more F.U.D.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent [online Game demo](http://gwan.com/blog/20121001.html) presented at the `ORACLE Open World` expo in SFO, we did not use `voltDB` but rather `ORACLE noSQL`, which is a Java (distributed) KV store.

Since we used G-WAN as a Database cache accelerator for `100 millions of records` updated in realtime (on one single server), I guess that this experience is relevant in your case because voltDB does not handle this kind of TPS rates.

You say very little about your project so I will describe what we did in our demo: the C servlet created worker threads. Some were used to update the position (direction, orientation, speed) of the bots, and others were used to push the modifications to the remote Java-based noSQL KV store.

This allowed this same servlet to reply in realtime to human players that sent their new position and queried the lists of all nearby bots (also parallelized).

This was made possible by the fact that G-WAN supports both C and Java servlets: C offered compact data structures for the cache (100 millions of records consume a fair amount of RAM) and Java allowed G-WAN to talk to the noSQL DB.

I don't know what your application will be doing but at least you have an example of such a case using G-WAN and a (huge) DB that had to react in realtime.

G-WAN supports C and C++ servlets so you can use your favorite C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I work at VoltDB.  We aren't aware of anyone who has tried this, but we had a similar question recently on our forum: http://community.voltdb.com/node/1862.